# Xcode 6 Image not Visible on larger screens

Tags: image, xcode6, screen-size

I am using `Xcode 6.1.1`. Image with `Universal(2X)` is used in one of the view-controllers.

It is visible on small screen sizes(till `4.7 inch`), but not on larger screens. But would be the reason?

```
           Location: Relative to group, 
           Devices: Universal, 
           Width: Any, 
           Height: Any, 
           Types: Bitmaps, 
           Render As : Default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

The first thing you need to is enable `size class` options in `file inspector` in `xcode 6 storyboard`.
(`Xcode 6` has changed a way lot from `Xcode 5`).

[image]

***(Check Use Size classes here)***

The way it is setting constraints has also changed a way better.

Have a look at two way of constraints you can set up.

[image]

[image]

You might have noticed for the former size class, we can set constraints for any layouts.
`(which is mentioned below Base values)`. The later is meant for iphones in potrait and landscape mode.

For enabling constraints for different layouts. You need to install these layouts from the `attributes inspector` in `storyboard`.

[image: see i have checked wC hAny which means width Compact height any]

***(see i have checked wC hAny which means width Compact height any)***

In `Xcode 6`, they support `9 resolutions` with hierarchy level of applying constraints.

```
                  wC hC
                  wC hAny
                  wC hRegular
                  .
                  .
                  wAny hAny
                  .
                  .
                  wRegular hRegular
```